# The text is not flushed to the bottom in Koma-script

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, scrbook, parskip

I have a problem using the scrbook class. Since I updated my miktex (and the koma-script package), I noticed that the vertical alignment of my document has changed. The bottom of the pages are now ragged, that is the position of the last line changes from page to page. Has the glue/stretch of e.g. \parskip in koma-script recently been changed? How can I solve this problem?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=no,flushbottom,headinclude,paper=17cm:24cm,BCOR=14mm,pagesize=pdftex,DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[1]
\section{Section}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Section}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Section}
\Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\flushbottom`  manually and make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where should I add `\flushbottom'?

Comment: Try out some obvious places ...

Comment: I suspect the issue arose with the introduction of the `twoside=semi` option, in version 3.17.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't matter whether to put `\flushbottom` in the preamble or after `\begin{document}`. @UlrikeFischer If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: The bug is fixed and is available with the current KOMA-script release.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was a bug in KOMA-script that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\flushbottom` manually and make a bug report.